# OJS (Open Journal System) theme development: making adaptive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, themes, ojs

I'm finishing the theme development for Open Journal System. But I have encountered some troubles. The core's template functionality doesn't support template overrides. So in order to support dependencies after system updates I should adapt to native core template handling without any core modifications.

The theme is hosted here:

https://www3.mruni.eu/ojs/sustainable-development-strategy

To practical part:

I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap 3 and I would like to make all pages responsive and mobile friendly.

1). All images with JS receives 'img-responsive' class.
But the Firefox doesn't resize properly the images from lower corner of right sidebar.
With Chrome - everything is OK

2). The most problematic part. As I resize the browser's window the horizontal scrollbar  appears.

I can't fix those problems so waiting for some help

3). If you have some advice how to make it more mobile friendly - I will appreciate it